# Remove Selection from Last Li Element

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to remove the last `a` tag from the last element using CSS but it doesn't seem to work

Here is what I want to do:

[image]

and here is my code

```html
<div class="menu-map">
    <ul>
        <li><a class="chp" href="#">test1</a></li>
        <li><a class="chp" href="#">test2</a></li>
        <li><a class="chp" href="#">test3</a></li>
        <li><a class="chp" href="#">test4</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS :

```css
.menu-map ul {
    font-size: 20px;
}
.menu-map ul li {
    display: inline-block;
}
.chp {
    text-transform: capitalize;
    color: #312e2e;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
.menu-map ul li::after {
    content: ' > ';
    margin: 10px;
}
.chp:hover , .chp:hover::after {
    color: rgb(39, 135, 214);
}
.menu-map ul li:last-child::after {
    content: none;
}
```

how can I remove a selection or a tag from the last element (test 4) to work dynamically?

Comment: If you don’t want this link to be clickable, then use `pointer-events: none` on it. (It might still be activatable via keyboard navigation then though.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your purpose is to disable the linking of the last `a`, add this to the CSS

```
.menu-map ul li:last-child a {
    color: inherit;
    text-decoration: none;
    pointer-events: none;
    user-select: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Like that? it's like your screen

```css
.menu-map ul {
    font-size: 20px;
}
.menu-map ul li {
    display: inline-block;
}
.chp {
    text-transform: capitalize;
    color: #312e2e;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
.menu-map ul li::after {
    content: ' > ';
    margin: 10px;
}

.menu-map ul li:last-child:hover {
     color: rgb(39, 135, 214);
}
.menu-map ul li:last-child::after {
     content:none;
}
.menu-map ul > li > a {
    color: inherit;
    text-decoration: none;
    pointer-events: none;
    user-select: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu-map">
    <ul>
        <li><a class="chp" href="#">test1</a></li>
        <li><a class="chp" href="#">test2</a></li>
        <li><a class="chp" href="#">test3</a></li>
        <li><a class="chp" href="#">test4</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```